# i am getting error while importing @google-cloud/storage

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, google-cloud-storage, nuxt.js

I am getting error just after importing @google-cloud/storage

Environment details

- OS: macOS Big Sur
- Node.js version: v12.18.4
- npm version:6.14.6
- @google-cloud/storage version:^ 5.6.0
- framework nuxt js version : Nuxt.js @ v2.14.7

**Steps to reproduce**

- install @google-cloud/storage

  yarn add @google-cloud/storageor npm install @google-cloud/storage --save

import it

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
keyFilename : path.join(__dirname, './file.json'),
projectId: "xxx-xxx-xxx"
});
```

just after that i got this error

`ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth' ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src' ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src' ERROR in ./node_modules/configstore/node_modules/make-dir/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/make-dir' ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth' ERROR in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src' ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/graceful-fs' ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/gtoken/build/src' ERROR in ./node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/write-file-atomic' ERROR in ./node_modules/http-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/http-proxy-agent/dist' ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist' ERROR in ./node_modules/http-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/http-proxy-agent/dist' ERROR in ./node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist`'

i tried to override webpack config by adding

```
 config.node : {
        fs: 'empty', 
        net: 'empty', 
        tls: 'empty', 
        child_process: 'empty', 
        __filename: true, 
        __dirname: true
     }
```

That’s the only solution i found but i still getting error

```
TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
    at promisify (util.js?3022:602)
    at eval (index.js?5051:7)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/get-stream/index.js (index.js:275)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854)
    at fn (runtime.js:151)
    at Object.eval (file.js?5fe9:20)
    at eval (file.js:3042)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js (index.js:167)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854)
    at fn (runtime.js:151)
```

Comment: try deleting projectId, on the docs says when you use keyFilename 
 projectId  is not necessary https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#StorageOptions

Comment: @Pablote i am getting this error just by importing @google-cloud/storage
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

Comment: Looks like OP filed an [open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1363) and others are encountering it as well. I believe this issue is best addressed by the maintainers of the client library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem you are using @google-cloud/storage on client side code, this lib is supposed to be used on [server side only](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2211).

remember Nuxt is a SSR(server side render) even if it render on server a lot of the code will be on client side too. You can try to use this on serverside components like [The serverMiddleware Property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/)

to run storage on client side try to use [npm firebase storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)